# how to add items to array without creating duplicates in cart in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

so i have a shopping cart system that is working. but i cannot make it increment without it creates duplicates in the cart. how can i have it increment the item if it found an existing item in the cart + i want to have a increment and decrement counter buttons on the items in the cart.

the addtocart function in pinia work but the if statement with item.quantity++ does not work.

this is my code:

shop.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Shop</h1>
    Items in cart: <CartLength :count="cartnum">{{ count }}</CartLength>
    <div v-for="item in Products" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}$
      <button @click="storeCounter.addToCart(item)">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

pinia file

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useCounterStore = defineStore("counter", {
  state: () => ({
    cart: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    addToCart(item) {
      let cartItemIndex = this.cart.findIndex((x) => x === item);

      if (cartItemIndex >= 1) {
        item.quantity++;
      } else {
        this.cart.push(item);
      }
    },
    removeFromCart(id) {
      let cartItemIndex = this.cart.findIndex((x) => x === id);

      if (cartItemIndex >= 0) {
        this.cart.splice(cartItemIndex, 1);
        console.log("Removed from cart");
      }
    },
  },
});
```

db.json as my db with the items in it

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "iphone",
    "price": 2000,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "galaxy",
    "price": 3000,
    "quantity": 1
  }
]
```

cart.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="cart">
        <h1>Cart</h1>
        <div class="cartitems" v-for="item in storeCounter.cart" :key="item">
            {{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}$
            <button @click="storeCounter.removeFromCart(item)">X</button>
        </div>
        <h4>Total Price: {{ cartSum }}</h4>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useCounterStore } from "../stores/counter";
import { computed } from "vue";

const storeCounter = useCounterStore();

const cartSum = computed(() => {
    let total = 0;
    storeCounter.cart.forEach((item) => {
        total += item.price;
    });
    return total;
});
</script>
```

Comment: using `===` to test object equality doesn't work that way.  it will only return true if both objects are the exact same object in memory, so even if two objects have the exact same keys and values they will not be seen as "equal" with `===`.  it's much easier to test against unique object properties, for example `id` which your objects thankfully have, so you can do `this.cart.findIndex((x) => x.id === item.id)`

Comment: @yoduh but when i do that i cannot see the items in the cart as i cannot do "item.id" in the cart.vue for loop... so what to do?

Comment: you don't need to change the for loop at all.  my suggestion will let you _correctly_ find the index of the existing item in the `addToCart` method.  no other code needs to change to do that.  I did just spot one additional bug `cartItemIndex >= 1` is incorrect because 0 is a valid index it should be `cartItemIndex >= 0`

Comment: @yoduh it did not work.

Comment: Please give more detailed feedback.  Add the new code you've tried to your question so we can see that you implemented the code correctly. Explain what the result is of your new code besides "not working", i.e. add console.log statements.  What is the value of `cart`, `item`, `cartIndex`, etc. before and after different statements execute?  Without details I unfortunately can't give any more specific advice.

Comment: @yoduh thanks but i got this working already.

Comment: Can you post what your solution was?  People with a similar issue may search for and find this question in the future, and it'd be very helpful for you to include an answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line `this.cart.findIndex((x) => x === item)` to `this.cart.findIndex((x) => x.id === item.id)`. Assuming that ID is unique.

Comment: still the same issue...

Comment: Try `this.cart.splice(cartItemIndex, 1, {...item, quantity: item.quantity+1 })`

Comment: Before that, make sure you are using the quantity field to calculate your prices or displaying it somewhere so that you can ensure whether it is updating properly or not.

Comment: why splice? i need to add not delete...

Comment: Just to make sure deeply nested state update is picked up by pinia.